# Configuración log4j, distintos destinos

Tags: java, spring, log4j

Estoy implementando log4j para guardar guardar un log de excepciones del proyecto en spring, pero quiero tener otra fuente que sea la consola.

Cuando haga log.error("error ") deseo que se guarde en el archivo (Ya funciona).

Pero quiero que cuando tenga un log.debug("info") este sea enviado a la consola

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, CONSOLE,errorfile,fatalfile
#log4j.rootLogger=debug, CONSOLE

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

#Redirect to Tomcat logs folder
#log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/logging.log

log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}.%M:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.errorfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.errorfile.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.errorfile.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.errorfile.File=C:\\log\\errorlogging.log
log4j.appender.errorfile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.errorfile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.errorfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.errorfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}.%M:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.fatalfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fatalfile.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.fatalfile.Threshold=FATAL
log4j.appender.fatalfile.File=C:\\log\\fatallogging.log
log4j.appender.fatalfile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.fatalfile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.fatalfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fatalfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}.%M:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x \u2013 %m%n
```

pero cuando hago log.error("error ") y log.debug("info") solo me muestra el error, 
y cuando cambio en el root el INFO por debug, solo me sale el debug.

Alguna idea?, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar https://sentry.io/ es una plataforma para control de errores.

Ahora para tu caso prueba con esto [Log4j.ConsoleAppender](https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/log4j-console-appender-example/.)

```
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.immediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.console.encoding=UTF-8
# para que imprima debug
log4j.appender.console.threshold=debug

...
// Log en la consola
 logger.debug("Log4j consola !!");
```

Comment: Hola, gracias, pero como le indico que me saque por consola solo lo que envió por ejemplo en un log.info("something");

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta agregando la opción `threshold` lee https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/logging-levels-in-log4j/